# How do you make sense of the difference in addresses of local variables residing in a particular stack/function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out whether a stack grows up or down and I see the difference in local variables is positive, indicating it's growing down but curious as to how come the difference is 6 for `double` and 12 for `int`? That means the variables are 6 bytes apart (each residing in a specific stack) but not sure what's defining the size here given there's only one variable defined in a function (actually 2 with a function argument).

```
void stack(double *p) {
    double temp;
    
    if (p == NULL) {
        stack(&temp);
    }
    printf ("Diff: %d\n", p - &temp);  // 6
}
int main() {
    stack(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't mean the variables are 6 bytes apart. It means they are 6 *elements* apart.

Comment: you're right about it. it's pointer arithmetic

Comment: For the difference in bytes: `printf ("Diff: %d\n", p - &temp)` -> `printf("Diff: %d\n",(char*)p - (char*)&temp)`

Comment: that's fine. not what I wanted to get at but was curious about the *number* we are getting

Comment: Are you asking about how your particular unnamed compiler on an unnamed OS sets up the stack? (and if so, why?)

Comment: If you want to make sens out of these numbers you need to have a look at the assembly output generated by the compiler, like here: https://www.godbolt.org/z/j8MvjK

Comment: The ABI defines the size. Also, subtracting two pointers that aren't pointing at the same array invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This code shows 4 bytes between `int`s and 8 between `long`s, which agrees with what I expect for my platform and compiler.

```
 int a;
 int b;
 long c;
 long d;
 int d_int = (char *)&a - (char *)&b;
 int d_long = (char *)&c - (char *)&d;
 printf ("distance between ints = %d\n", d_int);
 printf ("distance between longs = %d\n", d_long);
```

However, packing of data on the stack is architecture- and compiler-dependent. Note all platforms will pack `char` values next to each other, but will pad them to a word size. It's perhaps best not to read too much into these findings.